# Styling the submit button on multiple forms 8.2

Tags: css, submit, kentico, submit-button

I am using Kentico 8.2 and running into the issue where I need to have different styles for my forms. I have been able to alter the input attributes without a problem, and thereby create different styling for the forms in the site. However, I cannot get the .FormButton to change style if attached to my CSS for the button, ie .newPage .FormButton { background:red color:white }.

Is there another way to populate a CSS on top of the form button in 8.2 without having to add a class attribute in the code behind?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to touch the code behind. You can just wrap the form in a div with a CSS class using either content before/after or a web part container and leverage [CSS Specificty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) by creating a more specific CSS selector including your new class (e.g. `.myRedForm`). The resulting selector would look something like this: `.newPage .myRedForm .FormButton { background:red color:white }.` The last resort would be using the `!important` directive which I would rather avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to render the form on a page and inspect the element by using F12 or FireBug.  Either one will allow you to view the source and inspect the elements in order for you to get your selector to style it accordingly.

You can also specify a css class by creating your form layout manually and adding CSS around the button.  Not ideal because you'd have to build your forms manually each time.